# How to add column to Team-managed Jira Kanban board

Tags: kanban, jira

Looked on Jira site but all articles I found were for Company Boards.
This is a team-managed board.

How do I add a "swimlane"  column to a Jira kanban board?

[image]

UPDATE

Someone pointed me to the Help

Comment: You need access to the Board option in the sidebar, then More > Configure board, and you can add columns from there. [From Atlassian](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/manage-columns-with-multiple-statuses-in-a-team-managed-project/)

Comment: That's the right Help file, but those options aren't available (I updated my question)

Answer (score 0):

The [Help](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/manage-columns-with-multiple-statuses-in-a-team-managed-project/) says you can just add that from the Board >far right select More (···) > Configure board.
However, that option isn't shown for me.

Instead, I had to [Edit my Issue Types](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/create-edit-and-delete-statuses-in-team-managed-projects/#Create,editanddeletestatusesinteam-managedprojects-Addorcreateastatusinyourissuetype%E2%80%99sworkflow)

[image]